# Trigger a function when a new document is created is not working

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have tried an increment counter example (https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/child-count) with Cloud Functions which is  referencing Realtime Database, but not Firebase Firestore.

I am following firestore document and tried some changes. Still facing issue and not able to run this code for firestore new document. I am writing cloud function first time, and I'm not sure I've written this right.

```
   exports.countlikechange = functions.database.ref('/posts/{postid}/likes/{likeid}').onWrite(
async (change) => {
  const collectionRef = change.after.ref.parent;
  const countRef = collectionRef.parent.child('likes_count');

  let increment;
  if (change.after.exists() && !change.before.exists()) {
    increment = 1;
  } else if (!change.after.exists() && change.before.exists()) {
    increment = -1;
  } else {
    return null;
  }

  // Return the promise from countRef.transaction() so our function
  // waits for this async event to complete before it exits.
  await countRef.transaction((current) => {
    return (current || 0) + increment;
  });
  console.log('Counter updated.');
  return null;
});
```

I want to update count in parent document.

Answer (score 1):

You should review the [documentation for Firestore triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events).  What you're writing is a Realtime Database trigger, because the function declaration is `functions.database`.  You'll want to use `functions.firestore` instead.  You're also using Realtime Database APIs instead of Firestore APIs.  Your final solution that uses Firestore will look almost completely different than what you have now.

Comment: maybe he's asking for code that shows how to implement this using firestore.